# Advanced online courses for different subjects

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, self-learning, education, descriptive-set-theory

During the pandemic, almost all the courses (basic or advanced) have been moved online instead of in-person. I was wondering if anyone knows online complete new courses for

1. Measure theory;
2. Set theory;
3. Descriptive set theory.

Any idea will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: This may help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380933/great-graduate-courses-that-went-online-recently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few years ago, IMPA recorded lectures on Measure Theory, which you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llnNaRzuvd4&list=PLo4jXE-LdDTQq8ZyA8F8reSQHej3F6RFX&ab_channel=InstitutodeMatem%C3%A1ticaPuraeAplicada). You can find the auxiliary notes here: [https://w3.impa.br/~landim/Cursos/MT.pdf](https://w3.impa.br/%7Elandim/Cursos/MT.pdf)

While I have not seen the measure theory lectures myself, I did follow the probability theory lecture series they recorded, which were of superb quality. I expect the same for this lecture series.